# Getting unexpected field name from ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes, file-geodatabase

Why does the code below come up with different field data names?

When I save in a GDB it comes up with underscore(*) on the end of the field name & when saved as .shp it comes up with no underscore(*).

```
import arcpy

# Envrionmental variable 
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Variables
in_StatisticsTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
in_ExcelFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
in_BufferFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
BufferDistance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
out_Feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)

try:
# Summary Statistic
   out_StatisticsTable = arcpy.env.workspace + "\out_SummaryStatistics.dbf"
   StatsFields = [["Area", "SUM"]]
   arcpy.Statistics_analysis (in_StatisticsTable, out_StatisticsTable, StatsFields, "Brgy")

# Excel to Table
   out_Table = arcpy.env.workspace + "\Out_ExcelToTable.dbf"
   arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion (in_ExcelFile, out_Table)

# Join Field
   in_JoinField = out_StatisticsTable
   joinTable = out_Table
   JoinField = ["Brgy", "ADD"]
   arcpy.JoinField_management (in_JoinField, Field,  joinTable, Field, JoinField)

# Join Field
   in_JoinField = in_StatisticsTable
   joinTable = out_StatisticsTable
   arcpy.JoinField_management (in_JoinField, Field,  joinTable, Field)

# Feature to Point
   in_HouseHoldFile = in_StatisticsTable
   out_FeatureToPoint = arcpy.env.workspace + "\out_FeatureToPoint.shp"
   arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management (in_HouseHoldFile, out_FeatureToPoint)

# Buffer
   outfeatureclass_Buffer = arcpy.env.workspace + "\out_Buffer.shp"
   arcpy.Buffer_analysis (in_BufferFeatures, outfeatureclass_Buffer, BufferDistance, "FULL", "ROUND")

# Intersect
   in_Intersect = [out_FeatureToPoint, outfeatureclass_Buffer]
   outfeatureclass_Intersect = out_Feature
   arcpy.Intersect_analysis (in_Intersect, outfeatureclass_Intersect, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```

Comment: You are using a reserved word most probably, have a look at https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010906.

Comment: oohh... i see now.. thanks much! I think finding a better acronym will be better thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are using a reserved word for file geodatabase (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010906), explained as:

> Using a reserved word as a column name will return an error indicating
>   that the column name is invalid. Copy/Paste from a data source where
>   the word is not reserved will add a "_" to the end of any table or
>   column name that is reserved within the file geodatabase